# Android facebook wait for AsyncFacebookRunner to finish?

Tags: android, facebook, multithreading

In my application, I have a ProgressDialog showing while the app do something:

```
mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
            ((FriendListActivity) ctx).getParent(), "Please wait...",
            "Getting data...", true);
    updateDisplay(true);
```

In updateDisplay method, it do someting like this:

```
items = new ArrayList<FriendInfo>();
    fa = new FriendListAdapter(ctx, R.layout.friendlist_item, items);
    setListAdapter(fa);

Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                getFriendList(); //This is where the problem occured

                initFriendList();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        fa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    };
                });
            }
        };
        t.start();
```

In `getFriendList()`, I make a call to get Facebook user's information:

```
AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(
                    facebook);
            mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends&fields=name,picture",
                    new FriendsRequestListener((FriendListActivity) ctx,
                            currentuser));
```

After that, the user's information will be saved in my database. And the `initFriendList();` method (below `getFriendList()`) will use that data to init the view.

The problem is I want initFriendList() wait until getFriendList() finish to get data. But in `getFriendList()`, I use AsyncFacebookRunner, so initFriendList() will run immediately. How can I make initFriendList() wait for AsyncFacebookRunner to finish before it run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to the android world, maybe these can help?

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#AsyncTask

Specifically ASYNCTASK

1. You can specify the type of the parameters, the progress values, and the final value of the task, using generics.
2. The method doInBackground() executes automatically on a worker thread.
3. onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(), and onProgressUpdate() are all invoked on the UI thread.
4. The value returned by doInBackground() is sent to onPostExecute().
5. You can call publishProgress() at anytime in doInBackground() to execute onProgressUpdate() on the UI thread.
6. You can cancel the task at any time, from any thread.

Explained really well here..

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzJmi59b6oI&feature=bf_next&list=PL3B389D29207777C7

On the right track?

--